# Electrically facilitated active transport across a membrane

Tags: human-biology, glucose, diabetes-mellitus, electrical-stimulation

I'm trying to go back to school to do a PhD in control theory, specifically concerned with control of glucose. The glucose system can be controlled using two chemicals: insulin and glucagon. I was wondering if there was any precedent for controlling the active transport of a chemical across a membrane using a tiny electric current. Has this ever been done?

The reason I ask is that I want to avoid relying on mechanical systems that are prone to being bogged down by attacks from the native immune system.

Any knowledge on the subject/recommendations for attacking this problem/alternative subreddits or websites would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to Biology. Electroporation is an example where DNA is injected into a cell using a (high?) current. But I think it works only with charged particles. Glucose is uncharged.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The glucose wouldn't need to be injected anywhere per se, just "let go" from a reservoir into the blood stream.

Comment: You may want to take a look at some of the research behind insulin pumps. I don't know the specifics, but I know they use a lot of closed-loop control, and are a fairly active area of research (but potentially difficult to get into--some people have been working on control problems related to glucose since at least the 80's).